# How can I display legend in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I wish to display my legend in `Tkinter` just like in `matplotlib`.

Say I have these three lines on my canvans:

```
from Tkinter import Button, Canvas, Tk

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas()
canvas.grid()

canvas.create_line(0, 0, 20, 20, fill='green', width=2, tags='line1')
canvas.create_line(30, 30, 40, 40, fill='red', width=2, tags='line2')
canvas.create_line(50, 50, 60, 60, fill='blue', width=2,tags='line3')

root.mainloop()
```

**How can I have a legend at the left bottom corner of the canvas like so:**

```
-------------------------
|   ——————     line1    |
|   ——————     line2    |
|   ——————     line3    |
-------------------------
```

The ASCII legend above is merely for illustration only. What I am really looking for is a nice legend done by a built-in function. I am not sure about its feasibility, though.

Comment: Can you give us some _functional_ code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no built-in function to create a legend**

You could use the `.create_text()` method to display text on the canvas:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.grid()

canvas.create_line(0, 0, 20, 20, fill='green', width=2, tags='line1')
canvas.create_line(30, 30, 40, 40, fill='red', width=2, tags='line2')
canvas.create_line(50, 50, 60, 60, fill='blue', width=2,tags='line3')

legend_text = """
-------------------
|   ------     line1    |
|   ------     line2    |
|   ------     line3    |
-------------------"""

legend_frame = LabelFrame(canvas,text='Legend',padx=5, pady=5)
legend_label = Label(legend_frame,text=legend_text)
legend_label.pack()

canvas.create_window(120,200,window=legend_frame,anchor=E)

root.mainloop()
```

## Result:

[image]

*Note : Unfortunately the `—` symbol is not a valid unicode character so I replaced it with a minus symbol `-`*

Comment: +1 and thanks for the a answer. It is absolutely a way. But I wonder is there any built-in function that do it for us? If we draw it ourselves, it is first cumbersome, second, it is a bit shabby.

Comment: @mavErick: _this_ legend is shabby, but it doesn't have to be. Just draw the legend directly on the canvas. You can give it fancy borders, backgrounds, fonts, whatever you want.

Comment: Great! This offers a really good starting point. May I ask how can I draw the lines inside the legend box? I wish to have three exactly the same lines in my legend. @BryanOakley

Answer (score 0):

The canvas has no built-in facilities for legends. It is simply a blank canvas on which you can draw lines, polygons, circles and images. You will have to write a function to draw a legend.